# Avro with Enum in Hive

Tags: json, enums, hive, avro, hortonworks-data-platform

I have this (shortened) avro schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "license_upsert",
  "namespace": "data.model",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "upsert", "type":
      {
        "name":    "EventType",
        "type":    "enum",
        "symbols": ["INSERT", "UPDATE"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Which just defined an ENUM.

I can easily create a avro file from some json data:

```
{
  "upsert": "INSERT"
}
```

Using the avro-tools, it all works fine, to and from avro.

Now, these avro files are loaded in an external table in Hive, and boom, hive tells me that:

> java.io.IOException: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found string, expecting data.model.EventType

According to the [doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe#AvroSerDe-AvrotoHivetypeconversion), hive does not actually support enum, but if I `DESCRIBE` the table, the field is seen as a string:

```
col_name | data_type | comment
-------------------------------
upsert   |   string  |    ""
```

Is there a way for me to tell hive that it should use a string? Even if I run a query not selecting the upsert field, I will get the same error.

### Note1:

I create table as follow:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events.event
PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT, day INT, hour INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'avro.schema.url'='file:///path/to/event.avsc'
)
STORED AS AVRO
LOCATION '/events/event'
;
```

### Note2:

If I generate data from the avro-tools (`random` command) the data is perfectly loaded in Hive.

The data I am actually using is created by [confluent](https://www.confluent.io/).

Comment: i can not replicate the problem, what hive version are you using? if i generate sample data from avro tools, it work properly

Comment: @lake Hive 1.2.1 from hdp2.5. Which version did you use? This is interesting. My hive files are generated by confluent (kafka hdfs connector). I did not load files generated by avrotools in hive directly, I just compared the output from confluent and the output from avrotools, and they matched. I will dig deeper,

Comment: Your comment make me think that you might be using a newer version of Hive, maybe with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14205

Comment: are you sure that it is exactly the same? did you see this Avro Enum type should be defined in Hive as strings, since Hive doesn't have a concept of enums. Ensure that only valid enum values are present in the table – trying to save a non-defined enum will result in an exception.
?

Comment: The output is the same indeed. I saw that an enum must be defined as string in hive, but as I am using only external table, I do not define anything myself in Hive.

Comment: can you specify how you are creating the table? did you try load data generated from avrtools?

Comment: I updated the question with more information.

Comment: it would be great if you can provide 2 records as sample .. it will make easier the debug :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that as said in the last line of the question:

> The data I am actually using is created by [confluent](https://www.confluent.io/).

It turns out that on output with the HDFS sink, `ENUM`s are converted to `String`s. As I created external tables in Hive based on my original schema, there was a discrepancy. Now if I just extract the schema from the file created by the hdfs sink, and use this one in the table definition everything works as expected.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/658 and https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/558